# Use OWL API to extract RDFS classes from ontology

Tags: rdf, owl, rdfs

I have an ontology that contains classes both of type owl:Class **and** rdfs:Class. I am using OWL API to parse the ontology.

I know that OWL API calls such as ontology.getClassesInSignature() can parse OWL classes from the ontology into OWLClass objects.

Is it also possible to parse the rdfs:Class objects from the ontology also using OWL API - or will OWL API only see the owl:Classes in my ontology?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but I'd *expect* that since RDF is only incidentally related to OWL, the answer is that the OWL-API won't do this for you.  You can work in OWL without doing anything in RDF at all.  It's just a convenience that you can map OWL ontologies to and from RDF graphs.  If the OWL-API supports this, it'd really just be for end-user convenience, not because it has a well defined semantics.

Comment: That's not correct, OWL recognizes rdfs:Class as equivalent to owl:Class. What the OWL API currently won't do is preserve rdfs:Class on save: those will be turned to owl:Class

Comment: 'OWL recognizes rdfs:Class as equivalent to owl:Class' believe this is in only OWL Full not DL or Lite. To the author: be aware of OWL subset you have chosen.

Comment: Thanks for all your replies.

Answer (score 1):

In short, yes. `rdfs:Class` and `owl:Class` are both parsed as `OWLClass` (or `OWLClassExpression` if they do not have IRIs but are complex expressions.

Beware of the results of modifying and saving these ontologies, though. Currently the OWL API won't preserve the original namespace declaration, and all classes will be saved as `owl:Class`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply - fortunately I won't be saving out a re-processed ontology, I'll be using it read-only but thanks for the heads-up.

Comment: @MarkS, rather than thanking people for their answers with a comment, use voting and/or acceping an answer that has been helpful to you. Have a look at "[What should I do when someone answers?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)" in the [help](http://stackoverflow.com/help) section.